# Nagra LB Problems

Tags: digital, recorder

Hi,

Just wanted to know if any one has had any problems with the Nagra LB in relation to files being corrupted. By this I mean, when recording on to the internal drive, on playback after dumping, there is sound then a click and then nothing. And this is intermittent. I have wavefiles that have this "silence" on and off throughout the recording.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried swapping out the drives? Factory Reset?  Also, does it do the same thing when you record to the CF?

Edit:

I have a few suggestions, but I'm just trying to figure out what you have / haven't ruled out so far...

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas:

- Make sure you have downloaded the latest firmware for your machine. The latest is V1.105.
- Have you listened to the files on the Nagra itself to hear if it is corrupted on dump down or while recording?
- What sample rate are you recording at? Maybe it's too fast for your internal drive?! Doubt that would be the issue, but who knows.
- Maybe check that it's not an operating system issue, sometimes there are issues with Snow Leopard because it's 64 bit... that might be an avenue. If so, then I'm sure they would have attended to the problem with the latest firmware. In other words, have you tried dumping down the sound on other systems?
- Have you tried recording onto a compact flash card instead of the of the internal hard drive?
- Try downloading [Soundhack](http://www.soundhack.com), open the files from there and change the header just to check if the whole sound is there?
- Have you listened to the sounds only after importing them into your DAW? Might be fine in iTunes, Finder, or whatever you use.